# Multiple Angle Integration

Tags: integration, trigonometry

What is the indefinite integral of $\sin(10x)\cos(5x)\sin(3x)$ with respect to $x$?

I have repeatedly attempted using integration by parts (setting $u = \sin(2x)$) to solve this problem, but I almost always end up getting an incorrect answer for some unclear reason. Can anyone please provide some useful hints or solutions?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to use $\sin(x)=(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/(2i)$ and $\cos(x)=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$.

Comment: I just realised there was a major flaw in my answer. However, until I fix it, use the method of integrating by parts such that the integral loops back to itself, so you can make an equation: $I=g(x)+kI$ where $I$ is the integral, and then you can directly solve for it that way

Answer (score 3):

Use $\sin A\cos B=\frac12[\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)], \sin A\sin B=\frac12[\cos (A-B)- \cos (A+B)]$:
$$\int \sin(10x)\cos(5x)\sin(3x)dx = \int \sin(10x)\cdot\frac12[\sin(8x)+\sin(-2x)] dx=\\
\frac14\int \cos(2x)-\cos(18x)dx-\frac14\int \cos(8x)-\cos(12x)dx=\\
\frac14\left[\frac1{2}\sin (2x)-\frac1{18}\sin (18x)-\frac18\sin(8x)+\frac1{12}\sin(12x)\right]+C$$
Also, $\sin(-2x)=-\sin(2x)$.

Wolframalpha [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20%5Csin%2810x%29%5Ccos%285x%29%5Csin%283x%29dx).

Comment: I got the same thing by using the product-to-sum formulas on the sine terms first, then multiplied by $\cos 5x$ and used the sum-to-product formula again.  Then I was able to use $\cos (-x) = \cos (x)$ and I had the same four (very easy!) integrals you did.